# When using sapply,I get Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:31: unexpected symbol 1 ^

Tags: r, error-handling, sapply

When run this code,I will get an error:

```
genes<-colnames(survdata)[-c(1:3)]
univ_formulas<-sapply(genes,function(x)as.formula(paste('Surv(OS,status)~',x)))
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:31: unexpected symbol
1: Surv(OS,status)~ ABC7-42389800N19.1
                                  ^
```

If I remove the element and run the code again, a similar error appears again:

```
univ_formulas<-sapply(genes,function(x)as.formula(paste('Surv(OS,status)~',x)))
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:26: unexpected symbol
1: Surv(OS,status)~ CITF22-1A6.3
                             ^
```

I don't know where the wrong is.

example of the data:

```
head(genes,n = 50)
 [1] "A1BG"               "A1BG-AS1"           "A2M"               
 [4] "A2M-AS1"            "A2ML1"              "A2MP1"             
 [7] "A3GALT2"            "A4GALT"             "AAAS"              
[10] "AACS"               "AACSP1"             "AADAT"             
[13] "AAED1"              "AAGAB"              "AAK1"              
[16] "AAMDC"              "AAMP"               "AANAT"             
[19] "AAR2"               "AARD"               "AARS"              
[22] "AARS2"              "AARSD1"             "AASDH"             
[25] "AASDHPPT"           "AASS"               "AATF"              
[28] "AATK"               "AATK-AS1"           "ABAT"              
[31] "ABC7-42389800N19.1" "ABCA1"              "ABCA10"            
[34] "ABCA11P"            "ABCA12"             "ABCA13"            
[37] "ABCA17P"            "ABCA2"              "ABCA3"             
[40] "ABCA4"              "ABCA5"              "ABCA6"             
[43] "ABCA7"              "ABCA8"              "ABCA9"             
[46] "ABCB1"              "ABCB10"             "ABCB4"             
[49] "ABCB6"              "ABCB7"
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data?

Comment: Of course, the data is added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the names of the genes contain `-` which `base::str2lang` regards as a mathematical expression. We can fix this as follows:

- "Clean" gene names to convert `-` to `_` and document this somewhere.

We then have:

```
genes <- c("ABC7-42389800N19.1", "AATK-AS1")
sapply(genes,function(x)as.formula(paste('Surv(OS,status)~',
+                                          sub("-", "_",x))))
$`ABC7-42389800N19.1`
Surv(OS, status) ~ ABC7_42389800N19.1
<environment: 0x000002ad508b58e8>

$`AATK-AS1`
Surv(OS, status) ~ AATK_AS1
<environment: 0x000002ad508b3c30>
```

This is an illustration of why that is the case:

```
A <- 4; B<- 20
str2lang("A-B")
A - B
eval(str2lang("A-B"))
[1] -16
```

`str2lang` is essentially similar to the dreaded `eval-parse` framework. From the docs, this is what it does:

> str2expression(s) and str2lang(s) return special versions of parse(text=s, keep.source=FALSE) and can therefore be regarded as transforming character strings s to expressions, calls, etc.

**NOTE**

1. Since this is to be used in modeling, it is probably better to perform the `sub` at the `colnames` stage such that the input data to the model has the names we expect:

```
# not tested but you get the idea
colnames(survdata)[-c(1:3)]<-sub("-", "_",colnames(survdata)[-c(1:3)])
```

2. It is important, for biological/research purposes, to document why gene names where cleaned as suggested in this answer.