# Emmeans package: Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:21: unexpected symbol

Tags: r, error-handling, anova, emmeans

I'm not familiar with R at all but have to run this code for uni, not able to make it work. I want to do pairwise comparison for my ANOVA test, any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
comp <- emmeans(anova_A, specs=pairwise ~ mydata$`Which group of people influences your decisions about sustainable food options the most?`, model="univariate")
```

And it shows this error message:

> Error in str2lang(x) : :1:21: unexpected symbol
> 1: pairwise~mydata.Av1.`Which group of people influences your decisions about sustainable food options the most?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When using sapply,I get Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:31: unexpected symbol 1 ^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313780/when-using-sapply-i-get-error-in-str2langx-text131-unexpected-symbol-1)

Comment: Try my [answerr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70315310/10323798) from yesterday :) I think you've also got the formula syntax wrong. It seems unusual to specify a formula using `$`.

Comment: you will find it much easier going forward if you convert all of your variable names to be syntactically valid e.g. running `names(yourData) <- make.names(names(yourData))` is one way

Answer (score 3):

If you really have a variable by that name in your model, then the following should work:

```
EMM <- emmeans(anova_A, "Which group of people influences your decisions about sustainable food options the most?")
pairs(EMM)
```

In any case, you specify names of predictors used in the *model*, because `emmeans()` summarizes the model, not the data set.